# Which is the differences between this two configurations?

Tags: spring, security, ldap

I am using SpringSecurity and I have two configurations to try. In my security-config.xml I have the following content to authenticate a user against LDAP.

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <ldap-authentication-provider server-ref="ldapLocal"
        user-search-filter="(| (userPrincipalName={0}) (sAMAccountName={0}))" user-search-base="CN=particion1,DC=prueba,DC=com">
    </ldap-authentication-provider>
```

But I recieve the following error

```
[LDAP: error code 49 - 8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 2030, v1db1}
```

I have this configuration in my properties file

```
app.ad-domain=prueba
app.ad-server=ldap://localhost/
app.ad-rootdn=CN=particion1,DC=prueba,DC=com
app.service-principal=HTTP/localhost@prueba
app.keytab-location=/tmp/tomcat.keytab
app.ldap-search-base=CN=particion1,DC=prueba,DC=com
app.ldap-search-filter="(| (userPrincipalName={0}) (sAMAccountName={0}))"
```

Can I call this properties somehow? Or could anyone helps to me to use this configuration in xml file?

**UPDATE**

Now I have this configuration

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <ldap-authentication-provider
        user-search-filter="(| (userPrincipalName={0}) (sAMAccountName={0}))" user-search-base="CN=particion1,DC=prueba,DC=com"></ldap-authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<ldap-server url="ldap://192.168.5.2"
    manager-dn="CN=part1,DC=test,DC=com" manager-password="" />
```

And I recieve the following error

```
Configuration problem: You must specify the manager-password if you supply a CN=test,DC=prueba,DC=com
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/user-directory-sync-fails-with-ldap-error-code-49-223217565.html it is related to user/password/account pb

So are you sure the property file is working? Because I do not see the difference between xml file or property file.

This a config working for me:

```
<authentication-manager alias='authenticationManager'>
<ldap-authentication-provider user-search-filter='(uid={0})' user-search-base='${myserviceservice.user.search.base}></ldap-authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<ldap-server url="${myservice.read.scheme}://${myservice.read.host}" manager-dn="${myservice.nontrans.user}" manager-password="dummy-password" />
```

and it does not seem far from yours.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but I don't have any password in LDAP to authenticate I need to disable this option I think so..